# Best way to store a BlackJack hand?

Tags: c, playing-cards, blackjack

First off, I'm still new to C, so please let me know about any suggestions you can make (especially about handling arrays).

I want to store a BlackJack hand in C. I've come to the conclusion that a hand or card has to be a string, because cards can be both characters: `A, J, Q, K` or numbers: `1, 2.. 10`, where 10 should actually be a string of two characters.

Now, I tried storing cards making up a hand into an array like this:

```
char* hand;
hand[1] = "A";
hand[2] = "2";
```

The problem is the `10`, which takes up two indices of the array instead of one. A way I could get around this would just be to create a struct with 5 strings (the maximum number of cards in a BlackJack hand), one for each card. However, what if I, for some reason, wanted to have a hand of thousands of cards? What would be the best way to store a hand then?

Comment: You could use `"T"` to represent 10. As for a hand of thousands of cards, you can use a number to represent the cards instead of a single letter string.

Comment: I guess I didn't exactly state my intentions clearly enough, but I'm trying to print out my hand to an LCD for an embedded systems project. My LCD screen is quite limited so it'd be best if I print out J, Q, or K instead of 11, 12, 13.

Comment: Printing and storage are different concerns. Obviously they're not independent but when choosing a storage format you need to state your requirements and constraints. You could store a hand as an image of what you want displayed on screen but that might not be easy to read and interpret in another part of your application.

Comment: First thing to learn about C: NEVER use strings for anything, unless you really have to.

Answer (score 2):

You might find this site interesting.

http://www.computerpokercompetition.org/

They host an annual AI poker competition.  Their server is written in C, and you can download the code from the above site.

Basically, they store the cards as integers.  This is the most efficient way of dealing with the cards.  There are only 52 types of cards in the deck.  More if there are jokers present.  So you can map this into an integer value between 0 and 51.  They use the following function to print out what a card is, since an integer card number is not going to tell you much.  Notice they build the string based on rank and suite.

```
int printCard( const uint8_t card, const int maxLen, char *string  )
{
  if( 3 > maxLen ) {
    return -1;
  }

  string[ 0 ] = rankChars[ rankOfCard( card ) ];
  string[ 1 ] = suitChars[ suitOfCard( card ) ];
  string[ 2 ] = 0;

  return 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't store the cards as strings (e.g. `"9"`), but as chars (e.g. `'9'`). For the value `10` you could use a replacement char like `'T'`. Example code:

```
char hand[MAX_HAND_LEN];
int hand_len;

get_hand(hand, hand_len);

for (int i = 0; i < hand_len; i++) { 
    if (hand[i] == 'T') {
        putchar('1');
        putchar('0');
    } else {
        putchar(hand[i]);
    }
    putchar(' ');
}
putchar('\n');
```

This way you neither waste unnecessary memory (since one card now only requires one byte of storage), nor sacrifice code simplicity or readability.

Comment: ITYM `putchar()`. `putc()` requires a stream argument in addition.

Comment: Yeah, I mixed the two up in my head. Fixed.

Comment: Better than strings, but still worse than simple integers.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker In C, chars are integers. The smallest kind at that.

Comment: Yes, but if you're using chars like "T", "J", etc., then you have to have something like a switch to get values to add to a total. I mean have an integer representation in an order that can be directly computed with. And no, I'm not talking about compressing hands into a single value--I'm talking about using _arrays_ of integers for hands.

Comment: Okay, in circumstances where that single conditional branch really matters, you might have a good point.

Comment: It's also important for beginning programmers to understand that the internal computing representation of something and the readable-text representation of that same thing have very different goals, and it's usually a good idea to consider them separately.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an essay on the subject [here](http://etceterology.com/blog/2013/5/23/representing-playing-cards-in-software). Using strings is a really bad idea. Integers are better, and the best order to use is to put suit in the low-order bits, i.e, use the order 2c, 2d, 2h, 2s, 3c, 3d, ... Ks, Ac, Ad, Ah, As. That way, you don't even have to separate ranks and suits to do the math. Hands, then, are just arrays of integers. I can run *billions* of hands in minutes with this representation. The function in [my library](http://github.com/lcrocker/ojcardlib) to calculate the total of a blackjack hand looks like this (the OJ_CARD macro expands to an integer constant, so that compare is fast):

```
int ojb_total(const oj_cardlist_t *sp) {
    int i, c, t = 0, ace = 0, soft = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < sp->length; ++i) {
        c = sp->cards[i];
        if (c >= OJ_CARD(OJR_ACE, OJS_CLUB)) {
            ace = 1;
            ++t;
        } else if (c >= OJ_CARD(OJR_TEN, OJS_CLUB)) {
            t += 10;
        } else {
            t += OJ_RANK(c) + 2;
        }
    }
    if (ace && t < 12) {
        t += 10;
        soft = 1;
    }
    return soft ? -t : t;
}
```

That's from a general-purpose card simulation library and it's quite fast, but if I really wanted balls-to-the-wall speed from a blackjack simulation that did nothing else, I wouldn't represent cards at all, but just have a "deck" of multiple copies of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10}, and deal from that.

Comment: Your answer is technically the best, as storing cards in as few bits as possible is obviously going to give you the best performance when you're dealing with large volumes, so +1. That said, I feel this answer might be overkill for someone *"still new to C"*...

Comment: Using the whole library might be overkill, but the integer representation is as simple as it gets. If you're trying to learn C, the first thing you should learn is never use strings unless you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no single best way. However, `char *hand;` does not define an array of strings; you could use `char *hand[5]`, and the 10 would not take two indices; or you could use `char hand[5]`, and store the 10 as a single character, e. g. '0' or 'T'.

Answer (score 0):

Store the cards as integers:

- 1 = Ace
- 2 = 2
- 3 = 3
- ...
- 9 = 9
- 10 = 10
- 11 = Jack
- 12 = Queen
- 13 = King

For display purposes, translate the integers to their names using a translate function:

```
string GetCardNameFromNumber(int cardNumber)
{
    switch(cardNumber)
    {
        case 1:
            return "A";
        case 11:
            return "J";
        case 12:
            return "Q";
        case 13:
            return "K";
        default:
            return cardNumber.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I like @Amali's idea of using the letter 'T' or '0' to represent a 10.  I think that it's best to internally represent the card values as integers and convert them to characters for output.

Comment: This is tagged C, not Java :-) No strings, no  classes.

Comment: For more readability, you can declare an enum to give names to internal integers

Comment: Bad choice of order for integers. Requires divide by 13 to get rank. See [my essay](http://etceterology.com/blog/2013/5/23/representing-playing-cards-in-software) on the subject.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed you're not dealing with suits, so that ordering is acutally good. The function to return a character is more complex than needed though: why not just `"XA23456789TJQK"[rank]`?